# A clickable dotted pattern overlay on image with javascript and css

Tags: javascript, css, html5-canvas, processing

I want to achieve a clickable dotted pattern overlay on image with javascript and css but have no idea where to start with. Each dot will have a clickable url that is unique and assigned programmatically. Would be grateful if someone can point me to the right direction :) Thanks.

Original:

[image: Original]

Result:

[image]

Comment: Is this question about the Processing language? Which part is giving you trouble: creating the dots or detecting a click in a specific dot? Can you post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) showing what you've got so far?

Comment: For what it's worth, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/64wnkr69/1/) is a proof of concept I was working on in CSS before the question was closed. I was going to come back to it tomorrow to add in some JavaScript to set the initial position of the image and also to reposition it when scrolling the page, although I have a feeling you might have taken a performance hit with that last part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use compositing to create your dotted image.

**The dotted image effect:**

[image]

- Fill the canvas with black
- Set compositing to `destination-out` which will cause new drawings to "erase" existing (black) content.
- Draw dots in rows and columns. Each dot will knock-out the black underneath it making the dot transparent.
- Set compositing to `destination-atop` which will case new drawings to only be drawn over transparent parts of the canvas.
- Draw the image. The image will appear only in the dots.

**Responding to clicks on a particular dot**

- Listen for mousedown events.
- Calculate which dot the user clicked.
- Take the user to a URL corresponding to that identified dot.

**Here's example code and a Demo:**

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;
function reOffset(){
  var BB=canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  offsetX=BB.left;
  offsetY=BB.top;        
}
var offsetX,offsetY;
reOffset();
window.onscroll=function(e){ reOffset(); }


var PI2=Math.PI*2;
var radius=5;
var spacer=1;
var diameter=radius*2;

var img=new Image();
img.onload=start;
img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/dotimage.jpg";
function start(){
  cw=canvas.width=img.width;
  ch=canvas.height=img.height;
  //
  ctx.fillStyle='black';
  ctx.fillRect(0,0,cw,ch);
  //
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation='destination-out';
  ctx.beginPath();
  for(var y=radius;y<ch;y+=diameter+spacer){
    for(var x=radius;x<cw;x+=diameter+spacer){
      ctx.arc(x,y,radius,0,PI2);
      ctx.closePath();
    }}
  ctx.fill();
  //
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation='destination-atop';
  ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
  //
  ctx.globalCompositing='source-over';
}



function handleMouseDown(e){
  // tell the browser we're handling this event
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();

  mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

  //
  var x=parseInt(mouseX/(diameter+spacer));
  var y=parseInt(mouseY/(diameter+spacer));
  $('#position').text('You clicked dot at x='+x+' / y='+y);

}


$("#canvas").mousedown(function(e){handleMouseDown(e);});
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red; margin:0 auto; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4 id=position>Click on a dot.</h4>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks this is definitely working well. One further question, now I can get the x, y of which dot got clicked, if I want to do a hover to change dot color effect I guess I just need to do a current_dot.fillStyle='yellow' at the destinated coordinate and invalidate this when the mouse is away from the dot?

Comment: To add a hover effect on a dot, you'll have to listen for mousemove and `fill` the dot that the mouse is over. For efficient performance, you can add a second overlaying canvas to draw the dot on. Here's an example: https://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/y6ckz0fb/

Comment: Thanks @markE, your jsfiddle example is working nicely. I changed the spacing to 8px and make more spaces between the dots. Also I want to create an effect that when I click on the dot, the nearest 8 neighbour dots would be  "pushed" with animation from the focused dot (i.e. each of the 8-neighbour would move outwards by 2px) and then reverse the action when a user move / click on another dot. Is this possible? Thanks again for helping.

Comment: Your latest request (the "rippling water" effect) is a bit beyond the topic of this original question ;-)  It can be done, but it requires quite a bit of calculation. With your current effects plus the ripple effect, you would likely see some lagging performance on less powerful devices. Good luck with your project!

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I tried to look up the rippling water effect and seems most are demonstrating the effect in 3D. Any 2D examples you are aware of?

Comment: Here's an example of gridded-dots being repelled the longer the mouse button is held down. When the mouse button is released, the dots move back to their original positions. I have to say again...the accumulation of your effects will be noticeably slower on lesser powered devices: https://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/3f2w1ve7/